# Sporadically unable to connect to ubuntu 14.04 LTS server using domain name

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I use a DDNS which is automatically updated by my router every time a new IP address is assigned to the domain name.

The no-ip domain name is pointing to the correct IP address.

Currently I am trying to connect to my server in an FTP client. I can connect to the server using the IP address: 109.158.126.123. But I can not connect to the server using the domain name: crmepham.no-ip.biz.

Here is proof that I can not connect using crmepham.no-ip.biz:
[image]

-

Here is proof I can connect using the IP address: 
[image]

But then sometimes it does resolve the domain name and connects me fine. I have been in contact with no-ip who can't see any issues with resolving the domain name from their end.

What could possibly be causing the sporadic resolving issues? This is effecting all the websites that are hosted on my server also only sporadically being available, however always being available via the IP address.

The server runs Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Apache 2.4, I have setup Virtual hosts and Tomcat 7. All was working fine a couple of days ago under Ubuntu 12.04.

EDIT:

added nslookup:

[image]

And a further nslookup 3 minutes after the last:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your last edit with nslookup it seems that for some reason, the DNS servers that your ISP is pointing to your router are out of date or probably your ISP running a transparent proxy and they are caching the results of the no-ip checker. With the second command, which forces nslookup to use google DNS everything looks ok.

Most proxies that ISPs run are set to cache content only on a single port, port 80, so you will maybe get lucky by using a different port. According to [this](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/what-port-does-the-dynamic-update-client-use/) no-ip dynamic updater uses port 80, port 443 and port 8245. So change

```
http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update
```

to

```
http://dynupdate.no-ip.com:8245/nic/update
```

In your router configuration. This should solve the problem.

The other solution will be to change your DNS to google - this is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)

Comment: when I pinged crmepham.no-ip.biz it was trying to ping 109.157.206.92, which is not the correct IP address. But the correct IP address is set at no-ip. I used the commmand `ipconfig/flushdns' - sometimes this works and when I try to ping again it pings the correct IP address (109.158.126.123), but after a while it reverts back to the previous IP address.

Comment: @crm I have updated my answer. Please let me know if it resolves your issue.

Comment: why would this be necessary. My router is set to automatically update the no-ip DDNS when IP address change occurs. No ip change is occuring, but crmepham.no-ip.biz will keep trying to resolve to 109.157.206.92?

Comment: Ok, can you execute this two commands and tell me the result:

First: `nslookup crmepham.no-ip.biz` then `nslookup crmepham.no-ip.biz 8.8.8.8`? You can update your question with the result and let me know.

Comment: I updated my question with nslookup

Comment: @crm the answer is updated. See Edit 2 and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22630/discussion-between-shaddy-and-crm).

Comment: Your suggestion of changing the nameservers appears to have fixed the issue.